# Error when assigning function to variable

Tags: swift

I have simple code as following:

```
var println = print;
println("test");
```

It gives me error: `missing argument for parameter #2 in call`. I added more arguments:

```
println("test",".","\n");
```

It still gives me same error. Why does this happen?

Comment: Beneath your error message, after `in call`, does it have a `^` pointing specifically to a `println` call, or is there another referenced?

Comment: What exactly is your goal with `var println = print`.  Why not use a `typealias`?

Comment: @JAL A `typealias` only works with types, not functions ;)

Comment: Although I am also curious what you're trying to do here. The problem is that Swift doesn't currently write a thunk for you in order to propagate default function parameter values, so you just get the function reference without any default parameters (such as for `separator:` and `terminator:`). You could simply wrap it in a closure in order to have this thunk – e.g `let println = { print($0) }`. Although that'll only handle a single parameter to print, not a variadic list (and you won't be able to supply your own terminator or separator).

Comment: So why not declare a new function at the global scope?

Comment: @Hamish that feels funny... Is it a design flaw for function reference? It is corrupted and not working?

Comment: @texasbruce I wouldn't exactly call it a design flaw – there's just currently no language feature that lets you do it (it would probably need some form of special syntax). Although the case of "variadic parameter followed by other parameters" for closures is *definitely* broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition of `print` function:

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)
```

When you got a reference to it, you discarded naming arguments, as result all the inputs are treated as elements of `items` because of `Any...` that is not the predefined amount of arguments. Within such definition, there is no way to provide `separator` and `terminator`.

Her are function types as they are seen by Swift:

`print`:
[image]
`println`:
[image]

Comment: So that creates a loophole that when you take a reference to a func like this with vardiac params, you will never be able to call it successfully? I notice when you take a reference to func, it always drops the labels?

Comment: Right. I updated an answer with images to show actual function signatures of `print` and `println` as result of code transformations. I guess you need to create a radar for it. I assume such an assignment should inherit all properties of the original function.

Comment: @texasbruce I guess my answer is the answer to your question? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Unless there's some very specific reason you need to do it that way, this should achieve the desired functionality albeit in a more roundabout way:

```
func println (_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    for item in items {
        print(item, separator: separator, terminator: "")
    }
    print(terminator, separator: "", terminator: "")
}
println("test")
println("test",".","\n")
```